# Changing dictionary value types in python and Type hinting

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

What is the most appropriate way to handle typing when modifying the type of values stored in a dictionary?

For example, if I run the following code through mypy, it throws an error '... has no attribute "size"  [attr-defined]'.

```
from typing import Dict

import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as T

def to_tensor(my_dict: Dict[str, npt.NDArray[np.uint8]]) -> Dict[str, torch.FloatTensor]:
    for key, val in my_dict.items():
        my_dict[key] = T.functional.to_tensor(val)
    return my_dict

test_dict = {"foo": np.random.random((3,10,10)), "bar": np.random.random((3, 10, 10))}
test_dict = to_tensor(test_dict)
print(test_dict['foo'].size())
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Did you miss to import torch ? I can run your codes on colab without any issue .

Comment: The code itself runs but if I run the code through a static type checker like mypy then mypy throws an error because the type of value returned by to_tensor changes in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you define

```
test_dict = {"foo": np.random.random((3,10,10))}
```

you've completely defined the type of `test_dict` as `dict[str, npt.NDArray[np.uint8]]` as far as mypy is concerned.  You can use a different name for the result of `to_tensor`

```
test_dict_tensor = to_tensor(test_dict)
```

If you didn't need attributes on `FloatTensor` (though it's clear you do here), you could alternatively be explicit with the type of `test_dict` that the values can be either type

```
test_dict: dict[str, npt.NDArray[np.uint8] | torch.FloatTensor] = (
    {"foo": np.random.random((3,10,10))}
)
```

Note `X | Y` is alternative notation for `Union[X, Y]` in python >= 3.10 (and in python <= 3.9 if you have `from __future__ import annotations` enabled).

Comment: Thanks Joel.  Is it "unpythonic" to modify the types in place?  I understand mypy's strict typing but should I add an ignore or should I refactor the code?  I assume there is some memory impact if I instantiate two dictionaries, ie. test_dict and test_dict_tensor?

Comment: Also, yes, I can't wait to transition to 3.9+ to not need so many typing imports.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewStewart I don't know if it's unpythonic. Since you're using mypy it would seem a waste and perhaps a little confusing for future readers to `type: ignore` it. I usually only resort to that if mypy can't express what I mean. I can't comment on the memory impact.